# pointer non-type template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I don't really understand why the code below does not compile:

```
template<const char*>
struct Foo{};

constexpr const char s1[] = "test1";
constexpr const char* const s2 = "test2";

int main()
{
    Foo<s1> foo1; // ok
    // Foo<s2> foo2; // doesn't compile
}
```

Uncommenting the last line in `main()` makes g++ and clang++ emit the errors

> ```
> error: 's2' is not a valid template argument because 's2' is a
> variable, not the address of a variable
> ```

and

> ```
> error: non-type template argument for template parameter of
>       pointer type 'const char *' must have its address taken
> ```

respectively.

My questions are:

1. Why is `s1` instantiation OK and `s2` not?
2. Is there any sane situation where such pointer non-type template parameter is of any use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For 1.:

From [temp.arg.nontype]

> 1 A template-argument for a non-type template-parameter shall be a converted constant expression (5.20) of the type of the template-parameter. For a non-type template-parameter of reference or pointer type, the value of the constant expression shall not refer to (**or for a pointer type, shall not be the address of**):
>
> [...]
>
> (1.3) — a string literal (2.13.5),

`s2` holds the address of a string literal, and so cannot be used as the parameter here. `s1` on the other hand is an array of `char` that has been *initialized* with a string literal, but the value of `s1` (when converted to `const char*`) doesn't point to the string literal used in the initialization.

For 2.:

Function pointers perhaps? Still I can't say I've ever used a pointer as a non-type parameter.

Comment: upvoted for point 1, I am curious though what the reason behind it is

Comment: @vsoftco Sadly I am just a standardese parsing bot, I have no idea either.

Comment: seems extremely weird, afaik string literals are not temporaries but are stored for the whole duration of the program, so their address is for sure a compile time constant (or at least that's what I believe)

Comment: @vsoftco: Even if their address is constant, one should not depend on what that address is. More specifically, I don't think the standard will tell whether two otherwise identical string constants have the same address or not. If you would allow those addresses as template arguments, the question would translate into whether types obtained in this way are the same or not, and that can influence overloading resolution and whatnot. My guess is that they just wanted to avoid such questions.

Answer (score 10):

In a comment above, vsoftco adds:

> seems extremely weird, afaik string literals are not temporaries but are stored for the whole duration of the program, so their address is for sure a compile time constant (or at least that's what I believe)

That's true. However, the standard doesn't specify whether string literals have *unique addresses*.

Some linkers merge or deduplicate string literals. I have worked on systems where `"ello" == "hello"+1` actually evaluates to `true`. Other linkers are so dumb that `"hello"` in foo.cc has a different address from `"hello"` in bar.cc. Heck, some tiny C compilers are so dumb that `"hello"` can have two different addresses within the same translation unit!

For such a dumb linker (or compiler), should `Foo<"hello">` cause one instantiation or two? That is...

```
const char *sa = "hello world";
const char *sb = "hello world";
assert(sa != sb);  // this assertion is permitted to succeed

template<char*> struct F {};
F<"hello world"> fa;
F<"hello world"> fb;
assert(!is_same<decltype(fa), decltype(fb)>::value);
    // should we permit this assertion to succeed also?
```

The Committee admirably refused to open that can of worms, by simply prohibiting the construct.

---

Now, it's conceivable (to me, at the moment) that **sometime in the future** the Committee could mandate that all string literals be deduplicated by the same mechanism that implementations currently use for `inline` and `template` functions. That is, we can imagine a source-level transformation that turns

```
const char *sc = "yoo hoo";
```

into

```
inline auto& __stringlit_yoo_x20hoo() {
    static const char x[] = "yoo hoo";
    return x;
}
const char *sc = __stringlit_yoo_x20hoo();
```

Then there would be only a single instance of `__stringlit_yoo_x20hoo` (and only a single instance of that function's static array `x`) anywhere in the program, so the meaning of `F<"yoo hoo">` would be unambiguous. The implementation would have to name-mangle the thing unambiguously as well, but that's a simple problem once you've already committed to name-mangling things like `F<1+1>` and `F<FruitType,ORANGE>` (which C++ compilers have been doing forever).

...But then you would **still** have problems with those extremely smart linkers (like the one I worked on) that allow

```
assert("hello" == "hello\0world");  // this assertion is permitted to succeed

assert(!is_same_v< F<"hello">, F<"hello\0world"> >);
    // should we permit this assertion to succeed also?
    // Surely this way lies madness.
```

Comment: thanks for explaining the linker stuff, it makes a bit of sense to implement compiler this way, but I guess it shouldn't be too difficult either to maintain a unique address over the whole compilation unit

Answer (score 6):

There's a recent change in the relevant standard text, but the code is acceptable in neither version of the standard.

N4140 [temp.arg.nontype]/p1:

> 1 A *template-argument* for a non-type, non-template
>   template-parameter shall be one of:
>
> - for a non-type *template-parameter* of integral or enumeration type, a converted constant expression (5.19) of the type of the
>     *template-parameter*; or
> - the name of a non-type *template-parameter*; or
> - a constant expression (5.19) that designates the address of a complete object with static storage duration and external or internal
>     linkage or a function with external or internal linkage, including
>     function templates and function *template-ids* but excluding
>     non-static class members, expressed (ignoring parentheses) as `& id-expression`,
>     where the *id-expression* is the name of an object or
>     function, except that the `&` may be omitted if the name refers to a
>     function or array and shall be omitted if the corresponding
>     *template-parameter* is a reference; or
> - a constant expression that evaluates to a null pointer value (4.10); or
> - a constant expression that evaluates to a null member pointer value (4.11); or
> - a pointer to member expressed as described in 5.3.1; or
> - a constant expression of type `std::nullptr_t`.

N4296 [temp.arg.nontype]/p1:

> A *template-argument* for a non-type *template-parameter* shall be a
>   converted constant expression (5.20) of the type of the
>   *template-parameter*. For a non-type *template-parameter* of reference or pointer type, the value of the constant expression shall not refer
>   to (or for a pointer type, shall not be the address of):
>
> - a subobject (1.8),
> - a temporary object (12.2),
> - a string literal (2.13.5),
> - the result of a `typeid` expression (5.2.8), or
> - a predefined `__func__` variable (8.4.1).

The N4140 version is the one currently implemented by compilers. The N4296 version is somewhat more relaxed, but in neither case is the address of a string literal an acceptable template argument.

Presumably part of the reason for this is that template arguments must be mangled, and mangling a string literal in a sane way that would work across multiple translation units would be very difficult, if not impossible.